# How Can I Generate Super Dynamic Random Numbers In Lua Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I need to generate a random number dynamically that changes every seconds.

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: time1 = math.random(80000,180000)
 time2 = math.random(80000,180000)
 time3 = math.random(80000,180000)


 transition.to(blueTurtle,{x=50,y=350,time=time1})
 transition.to(redTurtle,{x=150,y=350,time=time2})
 transition.to(greenTurtle,{x=250,y=350,time=time3})

Comment: The probleme there is that it generates only at the beginning I want to generate random numbers each second Im stuck on this T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
local function numberGenerator()
    print("Random number:", math.random(80000, 180000) )    
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator )
end
numberGenerator()
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks I Solved It Now

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `timer.performWithDelay()` to do so. Like:

```
local function generateRandomNumber()
   local myRandomNumber = math.random(10000)
   print("myRandomNumber="..myRandomNumber)
   timer.performWithDelay(1000, generateRandomNumber) -- Rest of your calls
end
generateRandomNumber() -- First call
```

The timer syntax is as follows:

```
timer.performWithDelay( delay, listener [, iterations] )
```

Eg:

```
timer.performWithDelay(1000, myFunction,1) -- Here the 'myFunction' will get called once. 
timer.performWithDelay(1000, myFunction,2) -- Here the 'myFunction' will get called twice.
```

In both the following cases, 'myFunction' will get called infinitely.

```
timer.performWithDelay(1000, myFunction,-1)
timer.performWithDelay(1000, myFunction)
```

And, 1000 is the time in milli seconds. 
ie., **1000 ms = 1 second**.

You can find more about corona `timer.performWithDelay()` [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html).

Keep Coding................. :)

Comment: Awesome Thanks I Solved It Now